# Spring Security CORS call to spring removes headers from the request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, http-headers, cross-domain

I have a spring boot + spring security application in which I have allowed CORS (cross domain) call to the application.

I have following spring security configuration defined,

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/transaction/**").hasRole(SOME_ROLES)
                .antMatchers( "/", "/anonymous/pay").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter(LOGIN_FILTER_URL, tokenAuthenticationService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).maximumSessions(1);
```

And I have added below CORS configuration,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/anonymous/pay")
            .allowedOrigins("http://mydomain:8080")
            .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
            .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
            .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
            .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);

        // Add more mappings...
    }
}
```

Question :

When a request is sent on `http://mydomain:8080/anonymous/pay` from a different source (cross origin) the filters are still invoked and that too without the headers that were sent into the actual `/pay` call. It is noticed that an `OPTIONS` call is sent to server from chrome before the actual request is sent. But the headers are missing in `/pay` that were sent in actual request. As soon as the `StatelessAuthenticationFilter` is triggered the `HTTP` request does not carry the `headers` that were sent in the `/pay` call.

Any insights ?

Comment: Show request and response with headers for `OPTIONS` call and for actual call. For example a screenshot of your dev tool in your browser (F12).

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue recently and found a solution for it.

What happens is when you send a cross-origin request, in my case with a browser, a *'preflight'* request is sent to the same URL but with `OPTIONAL` http method and some headers (excluding the ones you added, hence they are missing).

Your Spring Security configuration denies authorization for this preflight request because it has been setup that way (unintentionally ofcourse) and you get a 403 response.

This has been discussed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5834) as an issue through which i found [this solution](https://github.com/chuan-su/klartext/commit/7c602fa20f57874c6cf3d80a1cbbf8bf7b1d14ba) by [chuan-su](https://github.com/chuan-su).

**[EDIT]** Found SO question by [Robert Schmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2628048/rudolf-schmidt) who had started the discussion linked above.

Basically you have to chain `cors().and()` to `http` in your spring security configuration and change the CORS configuration like this

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("*") //possibly redundant
        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH")
             // which ever methods you will be using
        .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type")
            // headers that you will be adding to your requests
        .allowCredentials(true);
}
```

If you are configuring CORS by injecting a CorsConfigurationSource @Bean, chuan-su has mentioned its setup in his solution along with the method given above. Do see the link.

**[EDIT]** Link to another answer that is *cleaner* approach according to the post itself. Haven't tried though but seems like it would work.